# How to pagination with spring data mongo @DBRef

Tags: mongodb, pagination, spring-data-mongodb

I want to pagination with Spring Data Mongo.From docs spring data mongo can do :

```
public interface TwitterRepository extends MongoRepository<Twitter, String> {
List<Twitter> findByNameIn(List<String> names, Pageable pageable);
}
```

If Twitter Document Object like this:

```
@Document
public class Twitter {
 String name;
 @DBRef
 List<Comment> comments
}
```

Does spring data mongo support pagination with comments?

Answer (score 2):

**Note: The code specified is not tested, it will just serve as a pointer for you**

The following mongo query limits the the array size to be returned:

```
db.Twitter.find( {}, { comments: { $slice: 6 } } )
```

The above mechanism can be used to enforce pagination like so:

```
db.Twitter.find( {}, { comments: { $slice: [skip, limit] } } )
```

You can try by annotating your method

```
@Query(value="{ 'name' : {'$in': ?0} }", fields="{ 'comments': { '$slice': [?1,?2] } }")
List<Twitter> findByNameIn(List<String> names, int skip, int limit);
}
```

You can specify that in your query like so:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.fields().slice("comments", 1, 1);
mongoTemplate.find(query, DocumentClass.class);
```

or you can try and execute the command directly using:

```
mongoTemplate.executeCommand("db.Twitter.find( {}, { comments: { $slice: [skip, limit] } } )")
```

### General Pagination Mechanisms:

General Pagination mechanisms only work at the document level, examples of which are given below.

For them you will have to manually splice the returned **comments** at the application level.

---

If you using the `MongoTemplate` class ([Spring-Data Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template)) then:

Use `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query` class's `skip()` and `limit()` method to perform pagination

```
Query query = new Query();
query.limit(10);
query.skip(10);
mongoTemplate.find(query, DocumentClass.class);
```

---

If you are using `Repository` ([Spring-Data-Reposioty](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories)) then use `PagingAndSortingRepository`

Comment: Robin - How we can create Pages from Custom List? Here I don't using Spring Data mongo repository method. Please help... Regards, Neha

Comment: Query Pageable API not working correctly. It doesn't gives total no. of pages